mocked useNavigate for Jest doesnt appear to update the path
I've got a multi step form and I'm currently writing a jest test to check that the user can move from step1 to step2 as expected.
In the test I can see the currentStep state is updating as the title changes but the form element remains the same.
What should happen is that navigate() should move the user to step2 which will show the new path of /step2 and the new form element.
I can see that useNavigate has been called its just not updating the path and I'm not sure why.
Heres my submit function thats being called in jest:
const onSubmit = () => {
    nextStep();
    navigate(`step${currentStep + 1}`);
  };

nextStep is working fine and logging currentStep out shows as 1 but navigate doesnt appear to fire.
Heres the test:
test('Move to the next step after form field is valid & submitted', async () => {
    render(
      // manually updating this to step2 shows the correct step in the form
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/signup/step1']}>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/signup/*"
            element={
              <Form/>
            }
          />
        </Routes>
      </MemoryRouter>,
    );

    await fillUserInfo();

    await clickSubmit();

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.getByText('Step2')).toBeInTheDocument();
      screen.debug();
    });
  });

Like I said earlier the Step2 text is showing as this updates depending on the  currentStep state which is controlled within nextStep() so this test is showing as working but when I drop a screen.debug in here the actual form element remains step1.
Had a look around SO and the greater net and all I could find was people checking for useNavigate to have been called, I can confirm its being called but I'm trying to update the actual path.
Also as you may see from my comment in the test, manually updating the path to step2 displays the correct form element.
So I guess my first question is, is this even possible and if so, what am I missing?
Edit:-
Each step gets passed an onSubmit prop. (Mentioned above)
And now that I've stopped mocking useNavigate like Drew suggests I'm seeing a new error:
ReferenceError: Request is not defined
   // Move to next step
   NextStep();
   navigate(`step${currentStep + 1}`);  
   ^
 };

This looks like my entire question has changed. I can see that I'm correctly rendering Step1 and clicking submit, from this new error I think I've just got to mock Request? Again had another look around but so far all the answers I've found relate to Node or Next.
For reference I'm currently using node v18^

Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the component and unit test code you are working with. You probably don't want to mock the useNavigate hook since you need that to actually effect a navigation change. We need more details.

@DrewReese Thanks that looks to have helped. Updating my question with the new error.

Can you [edit] to add the complete error message and any accompanying stacktrace? It may also be helpful to include the Form component code you are unit testing so we can see all that it does, and when it does it. I suspect you are unintentionally submitting a form.

In tidying up my test I managed to get it working.
So originally I was mocking useNavigate like so and trying to get my form to move to step2 after clicking continue.
 jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
   ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'),
   useNavigate: () => jest.fn(),
 }));

This wasnt working in the test but if I manually updated the tests path from step1 to step2 it showed the step2 component.
<MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/signup/step1']}>
    ...
<MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/signup/step2']}>
    ...

Unable to see why this was I thought it must be to do with the way I've setup my routes and rendered them in Jest so I setup routesConfig at the global level of my tests file like so:
 const routesConfig = [
   {
     path: '/signup/*',
     element: <RegisterForm />,
     children: [
       { path: 'step1', element: <Step1 /> },
       { path: 'step2', element: <Step2 /> },
     ],
   },
 ];

And rendered this out within the test like so:
 const router = createMemoryRouter(routesConfig, {
       initialEntries: ['/signup/step1'],
     });

     render(<RouterProvider router={router} />);

This is where Drew stepped in and suggested I dont mock useNavigate (thanks again).
This started to make my tests look like they were working but now I was getting an error around Requests, that lead me here: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/9508
Unfortunately that didnt help either, eventually I just thought to test the original use of MemoryRouter again without mocking useNavigate and it now works!
Heres the complete working test:
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import Form from 'Signup/Form';
import { MemoryRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

test('Moves to step2 when Next button is clicked', async () => {
    render(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/signup/step1']}>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/signup/*"
            element={<RegisterForm/>}
          />
        </Routes>
      </MemoryRouter>,
    );

    const UserType = screen.getByLabelText('New User');
    userEvent.type(UserType, 'checked');

    const nextButton = screen.getByText('Next');
    userEvent.click(nextButton);

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.getByText('Step2')).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });

That was alot, hope it helps anyone else in the future.
